# Basic Redshift query using lambda serverless really too slow

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

My redshift client app (running on aws lambda) has been stuck, even on local, never succeeds to get any data from a basic SELECT, even on small tables.

Same queries are fast in any Database client, but won't work anymore on my serverless.
Note : it used to work, and stopped working recently.

I used pg to process my queries, tried to switch to node-redshift, but it doesn't work either.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you might have some locks choking things up.  Do your queries run as expected from a bench?  Do you have many “zombie” sessions hanging around?

Comment: That was my first enquiry but : the issue is hapenning as on offline mode (local computer) and on staging environment (lambda).

Comment: Found my why : if PG is included in my service, it works, if PG is related to main project, it doesn't. But It ends to another infinity loop of issues...